# Unable to connect to MongoDB hosted on a different server - PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have created two AWS instances and have allotted two different Elastic IPs to them. One instance is used for the database server (hosted in MongoDB) while the other is for hosting the website.

I am unable to connect to the server through my PHP code. My code looks as under:

```
try{
    $connection = new Mongo('mongodb://107.21.230.121:27017');
}
    catch (MongoConnectionException $exception)
{
    print_r($exception->getMessage());
}
```

When I run this code on my website, I get the following error:

> "Failed to connect to: 107.21.230.121:27017: Timed out after 0 ms."

I have checked the server on which MongoDB is running. Using Mongo shell, I was also able to create some collections and documents.

Have tried all sorts of tactics without success. Can somebody suggest me where can I be wrong in the set up?

Comment: is that host allowed to connect to that database? Firewall setup?

Comment: I am not using any firewall. Also have not restricted any IP for connecting.

Comment: afair MongoDB only binds to localhost by default

Comment: Default setup is that mongo only allows localhost to connect, so you should check your config to allow other hosts to connect.

Comment: Install and try connecting via the mongo shell from your application server. This will confirm whether or not there is a connectivity issue.

Comment: Okay, so that essentially means I need to make changes to mongo.conf file to allow external IPs to connect. I have tried sudo --bind without success.

Comment: @JamesWahlin: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this out. What if this also does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from a quick and dirty nmap scan of your instance, it looks like you've not opened up the port (27017) in your Security Groups. This will need to be done on port servers.

Comment: I have tried everything to open up the port. This is all that I have tried:

1. service stop mongod
2. vi /etc/mongod.conf (to add my second server ip to bind_ip)
3. service start mongod
4. iptables INPUT -s <my other ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT

Still not running. I am not an old timer to MongoDB. Just making a transition from MySQL to MongoDB and it is hurting a lot :(

Comment: In the security groups on AWS you need to open up port 27107, this is not on the instance itself, it's in the ec2 console. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html